# Finding $ \int_{\gamma(0;1)} \frac{\text{Im}(z)}{z-\frac{1}{2}} \,dz $

Tags: complex-integration

I have a question that I cannot wrap my head around. How would I compute this integral using complex analysis techniques?

$$ \int_{\gamma(0;1)} \frac{\text{Im}(z)}{z-\frac{1}{2}} \,dz $$

I was thinking about whether I need to consider another function which is holomorphic (because $\text{Im}(z)$ isn't - correct me if I'm wrong). For example, perhaps I need to consider a function like $f(z) = z$, which would be holomorphic along $\gamma$ (again correct me if I am wrong).

How would I go about solving this problem?

Comment: What is $\gamma(0;1)$ ? And why not parameterize?

Comment: @NinadMunshi $\gamma (0;1)$ is a disk with origin 0 and radius 1. I would want to use Cauchy's Integral Formulae but I struggle to understand it.

Comment: How can you rewrite $\operatorname{Im}(z)$ in terms of $z$? Hint: On your curve, $\bar{z} = \frac{1}{z}$